# Display image that is saved as base64 / blob in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, base64, png, blob, jpeg

i have a base64 encode image (jpg or png) stored as blob in a mysql database.

How can I convert it back to the original image file?

Comment: Please give some details about which system you are using.  Also, what have you tried and how did it fail?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :-

`$data` is your base 64 data

```
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $data . '" />';
```

or try this :-

```
header("Content-type: image/gif");
echo base64_decode($data);
```

Comment: but my data is stored as blob, not as plain base64. does that make a difference?

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($image); ?>" />

Comment: **$image** your blob data try this code :)